# What are the nicknames that the Joker has called Batman?

Tags: dc, batman

I'm writing a short story about the Joker based on a mix of Jack Nicholson's and Heath Ledger's rendition of the character. I would like as many nicknames the Joker has for Batman as possible. Can anyone compile a reasonably comprehensive list?

Comment: I'm tempted to call this "Too Broad", but the more I think about it, there can't be *that* many; "Bats", "Batsy", and "The Dork Knight" are the only three I can think of - and that last one may have been Riddler

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27QA3hvamq0

Comment: "Dark Knight Defective," I recall from somewhere.

Comment: *Pointy eared freak* comes to mind, but it could be bleed over from McCoy in TOS.

Comment: I'm voting to close as Too Broad because of the sheer volume of Batman canons - narrow your scope down, please.

Comment: Yeah, too broad as-is.

Comment: @omegacron - I disagree. Cross - canon questions are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Zibbobz Even across all canons, how many could there be? maybe 10 or 15 nicknames? The answer would've been very interesting. This is another decent question closed for no reason.

Comment: @Daft That's the million dollar question though - how many answers *can* there be, across multiple comic story arcs not all of which are canon, several TV shows one of which is *prolific* in bad puns, over half a dozen movies, and an untold number of video games. But, if you think that's answerable, vote to reopen.  It doesn't help that the asker *explicitly* states that there is 'no one right answer' explicitly.

Comment: Since you're basing this character on the Jack Nicholson and Heath Ledger versions, why don't you narrow your scope to the nicknames used by the Joker in those two movies? That would make this an answerable question with a finite, unchanging answer.